# Manipulate with dynamic input

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, inputfield

I really new to Mathematica and I am working on developing interactive CDF. To understand the basics I start with a simple example but even with that I have a problem. In this simple CDF I want to able enter a function (Sin, Cos...)
This is the example that I started from

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[ x]}, 
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], Dynamic[Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}]]}]]]
```

But here I would like to be able not only change the function also the range and one more parameter such as frequency. So I know I need to use manipulate (I want to use as CDF)

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{f = Sin[o x + p]}, 
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], Dynamic[Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}]]}]], {o,
   1, 10}, { p, 2, 10}]
```

but here I can't change the function even I type `Cos` and slide the o or p it goes back to `Sin`.

Any idea how I can do this? Also what does Column function's purpose in here?

Comment: To answer your last question, `Column` just places the `InputField` above the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understood your question correctly. I might require to modify the code if I misinterpreted your OP.

**Example:**

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x], {x, min, max}],
 {{f, Sin, "Function"}, {Sin, Cos, Tan}},
 {{min, 0, "Min."}, 0, 2 Pi},
 {{max, 2 Pi, "Min."}, 0, 2 Pi}
 ]
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simple modification of your code that allows you to specify the function,

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{f = Sin}, 
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[f]], 
    Dynamic[Plot[f[o x + p], {x, -5, 5}]]}]], {o, 1, 10}, {p, 2, 10}]
```

[image]

Now you can change `Sin` to any built-in function that takes a single argument,

[image]

and still modify `o` and `p`.  You can even enter a [pure function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).  Here I'll use `Function[x, x^2 - 3 x^3]`, and the plot will be of `(o x + p)^2 - 3 (o x + p)^3`

[image]

Comment: I like this implementation +1

Comment: I am trying to carry this one more step further. I changed the idea from plot to take an integral.

Comment: @Erdem, the basic idea should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

this is an answer also a question at the same time. I am simply trying to avoid using sliders and predefined functions to increase the capacity of the CDF file. 
I changed my example to taking integral and use inputfield for the function and upper and lower limit. It completely functional but not best presentation and controls. Here is the code

```
Manipulate[Panel[DynamicModule[{f = Sin[x], xR = 1, xL = 0},   Column[{InputField[Dynamic[xL]], InputField[Dynamic[xR]], 
 InputField[Dynamic[f]], Dynamic[NumberForm[NIntegrate[f, {x, xL, xR}, WorkingPrecision -> nw], np]]}]]],{{np, 10, "NumberFormat"}, 10, 30, 1}, {{nw, 16, "WorkingPrecision"}, 10, 30,1}]
```

I have 3 input fields, Lower Limit, Upper Limit, and the Function

- First of all I would like to be able to insert name tags above or on the right of these fields.
- Second I would like to have a box for the result
- I would like to be able limit the input for lower and upper limit to numbers and incase user inputs a character gives an warning message.

For name tags I tried using FieldHint command but it did not work because I think I had to predefine a value for xL and xR and f.

Any ideas are welcome not only the answers I am looking for.

Thanks